# Unterschied zwischen "asiatischer Amerikaner" und "Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, difference, usage

> (a) Er ist asiatischer Amerikaner.
>
> (b) Er ist Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft.

Die erste Übersetzung von "Asian American" kommt in [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asiatische_Amerikaner) vor, die zweite im [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=asian+american). Gibt es Unterschiede in der Bedeutung, Verwendung oder hinsichtlich des Niveaus zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken?

Comment: *Amerikaner* anselle *US-Amerikaner* kommt mir schon wie Deutglisch vor.

Comment: @c.p.: Ist aber üblich. Man sagt oft _Amerika_, _Amerikaner_, _amerikanisch_, wenn man die Vereinigten Staaten meint.

Comment: @chirlu [Bei Google Fight sieht es aber so aus](http://www.googlefight.com/%22asiatische+amerikaner%22-vs-%22amerikaner+asiatischer+herkunft%22.php), als ob a) deutlich häufiger gebraucht würde als b).

Comment: @Matthias: Möglich, aber nicht unbedingt ein Widerspruch. Ich habe mir ein paar Treffer angesehen, bei denen der Begriff eben nicht einfach so benutzt wird; zuerst wird ausdrücklich oder implizit klargestellt, was damit gemeint ist.

Comment: @c.p. was würdest du statt "Amerikaner" für "Bürger der Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika" sagen? U.S.-Amerikaner ist das einzige, was mir einfällt, und dann hat man ständig die Abkürzung drin. "Aus den Staaten" hört man auch recht häufig, aber das wäre ja auch nicht eindeutig, schließlich gibt es mehr Staaten als nur die Vereinigten von Amerika.

Comment: @Philipp Ja, so weit würde ich nicht gehen. Man sagt letzendlich so gut wie nie *Bürger der Bundesrepublik Deutschland*. Mir (wie der Frage) geht es um die richtige *nutzbare* kurz auszusprechende Form.  *U.S.-Amerikaner* sage ich immer. Schreibe ich aber ohne die Punkte. Die beiden sind die richtigen. "Aus den Staaten" kann wohl falsch sein, doch eine Verwirrung –ob man sich auf ein Land oder einen Kontinent, welcher drei mal so viel Einwohner wie das Land hat, bezieht– gibt es nicht. Darum geht es Sprache.

Comment: @c.p. Sagst du jedes mal Niederländisch, wenn Du die Sprache meinst, oder ist dir vielleicht auch schon mal ein "Holländisch" rausgerutscht? ;)

Comment: @MaxRied Das ist eine völlig andere Sache. Menschen der gleichen Kultur zu verwechseln ist ja gar nicht problematisch. Jedoch sage ich nicht *Holländisch*. Doch *Holländer* habe ich vor Menschen gesagt, von denen ich weiß, dass die aus Rotterdam, den Haag oder Utrecht o.ä. kommen. Die fänden das, im Gegensatz zu NLändern, die nicht Holländer sind, nicht beleidigend. Vor Niederländern außerhalb Hollands sage ich, wie es gesagt werden sollte: NL-isch NL-er. Dieser Frage geht es aber um **schreiben**, d.h. etwas das alles lesen könnten, unabhängig vom Abstammungsort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Formulierung in (b) ist zwar etwas länger, aber lässt sich transparent auf jede geographische Herkunft anwenden, während das Muster in (a) nur für einige Ursprünge hinreichend etabliert ist. Im speziellen Fall wirkt *asiatischer Amerikaner* auf mich eher unüblich.

### Komposita

Daneben gibt es für manche Migrationsgeschichten Komposita wie *Italoamerikaner* oder *Deutschamerikaner*. Mir ist allerdings **Asiaamerikaner* o.ä. noch nicht begegnet, aber bspw. *Sinoamerikaner* bei chinesischen Wurzeln durchaus schon. 
Leider wird dieses Bildungsmuster gerade für Menschen mit deutscher Staatsbürgerschaft aber (oft am Aussehen oder Namen erkennbarer) fremder Herkunft häufig verdreht. Die werden nämlich gerne bspw. als *Deutschtürken* bezeichnet, während die logische Analogbildung *Turkdeutsche* wäre, denn das Rechtsglied bezeichnet in einem Kompositum normalerweise den wichtigeren Teil, der nicht weggelassen werden kann und durch den linken näher bestimmt wird, z.B. ist eine *Haustür* immer eine Tür. (Natürlich gibt es auch konventionalisierte Komposita, deren Bedeutung mit der Summe ihrer Teile nicht viel zu tun hat.) Mit solchen verkehrten Zusammensetzungen spricht man also (Nachkommen von) Eingebürgerten das Deutschsein ab.
Man beachte allerdings, dass *Deutschschweizer* nicht (nur) zugewanderte (Bundes-)Deutsche bezeichnet, sondern alle Schweizer mit (schweizer-)deutscher Erstsprache.

### Rassismus

Von der Grammatik abgesehen ist die Herkunftsangabe „asiatisch“ ohnehin viel zu ungenau bzw. vielumfassend, um irgendwie nützlich zu sein. Es ist eine tendentiell rassistische Feigenblattformulierung für Leute, die dabei eigentlich Menschen mit „Schlitzaugen“ meinen, so wie „afrikanisch“ synonym für angeboren dunkle Haut steht. Diese stereotypen Aussehen sind jeweils nur in einem bestimmten Teil der beiden Kontinente dominant verbreitet, d.h. „ostasiatisch“ und „zentralafrikanisch“ träfen jeweils schon besser zu, aber nie gut genug. 
Wenn im Kontext überhaupt sinnvoll, sollte man die Herkunft genauer bezeichnen oder aber das phänotypische Merkmal, auf das man sich warum auch immer bezieht, beim Namen nennen.

[image: C-Section Comics: “Political Correctness 101”]
Relevanter Ausschnitt aus dem [Comic](http://www.csectioncomics.com/2014/01/politically-correctness-101.html), den @Wrzlprmft in einem Kommentar verlinkt hat.

Comment: Re Deutschtürken: Es hat mich schon immer gewundert, warum es *Deutschtürken* aber *Russlanddeutsche* sein sollen.

Answer (score 4):

Eine allein aus sich heraus verständliche und korrekte Übersetzung für *Asian Americans* gibt es nicht. Wenn Du Dir den [Artikel in der englischen Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_American) durchliest, wirst Du feststellen, dass es hier um Menschen geht, deren Wurzeln in einem **Teil** des Kontinents Asien liegen - grob gesagt von Pakistan / China / Mongolei an in Richtung Süden / Osten:

> Today, Asian American is the accepted term for most formal purposes ... The most commonly used definition of Asian American is the US Census Bureau definition of Asian...
>   In the US Census, people who originate from the indigenous peoples of the Far East, Indian subcontinent, and Southeast Asia are classified as part of the Asian race; while those who originate from the indigenous peoples of North Asia (Russians, Siberians), Central Asia (Kazakhs, Uzbeks, Turkmens etc.), the Middle East (diaspora Jews, Turks, Persians, West Asian Arabs etc.), and the Caucasus (Georgians, Armenians, Azeris) are classified as "White".

Es gibt im Deutschen, soweit ich weiß, keinen gemeinsamen Oberbegriff für diesen Teil Asiens, bzw. keine eingeführte Bezeichnung für Menschen, die aus dieser Region stammen. (Vergleiche hingegen *Afroamerikaner*, das auch im Deutschen eine Abstammung nur aus Ländern südlich der Sahara meint.)

Wenn Du *Asiatische Amerikaner* (großgeschrieben) benutzt, gibst Du zumindest einen Hinweis darauf, dass es um einen eingeführten Fachbegriff geht. Je nach Kontext und Zielgruppe kannst Du dann noch erläutern, wie Du den Begriff verstanden wissen willst. Hingegen laufen die beiden Optionen *asiatische Amerikaner* (kleingeschrieben) und *Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft* m.E. stärker Gefahr, wörtlich, auf ganz Asien bezogen und damit anders als die englische Wendung verstanden zu werden. Falls Du das sogar beabsichtigst, würde ich b) bevorzugen, da es weniger widersprüchlich klingt.

In Deinem Beispielsatz verwendest Du den Singular. Ich weiß nicht, ob es dafür tatsächlich eine praktische Notwendigkeit gibt - aber wenn, würde ich das durch einen Verweis auf die Gruppe auflösen (wenn Du die englische Bedeutung meinst). Also statt

> <strike>Er ist Asiatischer Amerikaner.</strike>

lieber eine Wendung wie

> Er gehört zur Gruppe der Asiatischen Amerikaner.

oder

> Er hat bei der Volkszählung "Asiatischer Amerikaner" als Abstammung angegeben.

Comment: Bezüglich der seltsamen Verwendung von *Asian American:* [Political Correctness 101](http://www.csectioncomics.com/2014/01/politically-correctness-101.html)

Answer (score 3):

Zu (a):

> Ein asiatischer <*was auch immer*>

ist ein Asiate.

> Ein <*irgendwie beschaffener*> Amerikaner

ist ein Amerikaner.

Nachdem nun aber Asien und Amerika zwei Kontinente sind, die kein Gebiet gemeinsam haben, sind *Asiate* und *Amerikaner* Kontinental-Zugehörigkeiten, die einander ausschließen.

> Ein asiatischer Amerikaner

ist daher ein Oxymoron, also ein innerer Widerspruch. Tatsächlich versteht man darunter aber einen US-amerikansichen Staatsbürger, der Vorfahren hat, die in Asien gelebt hat.

Schauen wir uns die Umkehrung an:

> Ein amerikanischer Asiate.

Das müsste, weil es ja die Umkehrung des obigen Begriffs ist, eigentlich ja jemand sein, der in Asien lebt und Vorfahren hat, die in Amerika gelebt haben. So versteht man »*amerikanischer Asiate*« aber nicht. Die meisten Menschen werden darunter ebenfalls jemanden verstehen, der in Amerika (am ehesten in den USA) lebt und asiatische Vorfahren hat.

Der Begriff ist also nicht nur ein Oxymoron, sondern lässt auch mehrere widersprüchliche Deutungen zu.

»*Ein asiatischer Amerikaner*« ist grammatisch völlig in Ordnung, semantisch aber höchst bedenklich.

---

Zu (b):

> Ein Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft

ist klar verständlich und widerspruchsfrei. Diese Person hat asiatische Vorfahren, möglicherweise lebte sie früher sogar selbst dort. Aber jetzt lebt diese Person in Amerika und ist Bürger eines amerikanischen Landes (wobei man am ehesten auf die USA tippt).

Comment: Wenn jemand "asiatischer Amerikaner" oder "amerikanischer Asiate" sagt, warum sollte man in beiden Fällen davon ausgehen, dass es sich um einen Amerikaner handelt? Man könnte dann auch mit gleicher Argumentation sagen, dass in beiden fällen ein Asiate gemeint ist. Aber du preferierst anscheinend Amerikaner, wenn ich das so formulieren darf. Welchen Hintergrund hat das?!

Comment: b) ist klar verständlich, ja - aber ob es so verstanden wird wie _Asian American_, steht auf einem anderen Blatt.

Comment: @anion: Amerika, vor allem die USA, sind bekannt dafür, dass dort Menschen sehr unterschiedlicher Herkunft leben. Es ist nicht ungewöhnlich, dort Menschen mit europäischen, afrikanischen, indianischem oder eben asiatischem Aussehen anzutreffen. Ich habe den Eindruck, dass in den meisten asiatischen Ländern vorwiegend Asiaten leben, und Menschen, deren Aussehen auf eine andere Herkunft schließen lässt, dort selten sind. Daher treffen zwei Dinge zu: 1. Es ist schwer, ein typisch amerikanisches Aussehen zu definieren. 2. In Amerika ist der Anteil von Menschen mit asiatischem Aussehen größer ...

Comment: ... als der Anteil der amerikanisch aussehenden Menschen die in Asien leben. Daher ist es nach meinem Empfinden wahrscheinlicher, dass mit »amerikanischer Asiate« jemand gemeint ist, der asiatisch aussieht und in Amerika lebt, als jemand der amerikaisch aussieht und in Asien lebt.

Answer (score 1):

Vorweg: Als *Amerikaner, Asiate, amerikanisch* bzw. *asiatisch* verstehe ich jemanden, der langfristig auf dem Kontinent lebt oder lebte oder eine entsprechende Staatsbürgerschaft hat, und so verwende ich diese Begriffe im Folgenden.

- ***Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft*** ist ein Amerikaner, der zumindest die ersten Jahre seines Lebens (auch) Asiate war oder einen biologischen oder sozialen Vorfahren hat, der Asiate ist, und zwar innerhalb einer überschaubaren Anzahl Generationen.
- ***Asiatischer Amerikaner*** ist ein Begriff, den ich noch nie (bewusst) gehört habe und den ich nicht automatisch mit *Asian American* identifizieren würde. Insbesondere existiert nach meinem Sprachempfinden kein Unterschied zwischen *asiatischer Amerikaner* und *amerikanischer Asiate:* Beides bezeichnet eine Person, die man sowohl als Asiate als auch als Amerikaner bezeichnen kann. Ich vermute (kann aber nicht belegen), dass die meisten Verwendungen dieses Begriffes auf blinde Übersetzungen aus dem Amerikanischen oder Wikipedia zurückzuführen sind.
- Der Vollständigkeit halber: ***Asiaamerikaner*** oder ***Asioamerikaner*** würde ich als bewusste Parallele zu *Afroamerikaner* auffassen – mit der weitestgehend gleichen Schwammigkeit und den entsprechenden kulturellen und physiognomischen Implikationen, z. B., wie sich jemand identifiziert¹. Von den dreien, würde ich es am ehesten als Übersetzung für *Asian American* nutzen. Allerdings bleibt das Problem, dass im Deutschen *asiatisch* weit seltener für *ost- oder südostasiatisch* genutzt wird als das amerikanische *Asian* (zumindest meiner Wahrnehmung nach). Damit ist der Begriff so weit gefasst, dass er für kulturelle und physiognomische Beschreibungen (und damit überhaupt) selten nützlich ist – im Gegensatz zu *afroamerikanisch,* das z. B. genutzt werden kann, um über die Diskriminierung von Afroamerikanern oder die afroamerikanische Kultur zu sprechen.

Damit ergeben sich zum Beispiel in folgenden Fällen Unterschiede:

- Jemanden, der in Amerika lebt, Bürger eines amerikanischen Staates ist, nie in Asien war, aber der eine ostasiatische Physiognomie hat und dessen Urgroßeltern alle ihr komplettes Leben in China verbrachten, würde ich als *Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft,* aber nicht als *asiatischen Amerikaner* bezeichnen. Die Person würde wahrscheinlich als *Asian American* oder *Asioamerikaner* klassifiziert.
- Jemand, dessen Urgroßeltern alle Engländer waren, der eine europäische Physiognomie aufweist und der die ersten dreißig Jahre seines Lebens in Japan verbracht hat und der dann nach Amerika ausgewandert ist, würde ich sowohl als *Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft* als auch als *asiatischen Amerikaner* bezeichnen, aber vermutlich würde er nicht in das Schema *Asian American* bzw. *Asioamerikaner* fallen.
- Jemand, dessen Vorfahren seit Generationen ausschließlich in Amerika lebten und der eine europäische Physiognomie aufweist, der die ersten dreißig Jahre seines Lebens in Amerika verbrachte, aber seit vierzig Jahren in Thailand lebt, würde ich als *asiatischen Amerikaner,* aber nicht als *Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft* bezeichnen. Er würde wohl kaum als *Asian American* bezeichnet werden, eventuell als *American Asian.*

Die Problematik, ob sich *amerikanisch* auf den gesamten Kontinent oder nur die U.S.A. ist weitgehend unabhängig zu den obigen Überlegungen.

---

<sup>¹ zum Beispiel wird anscheinend Barack Obama vorwiegend nicht als *European American* bezeichnet, da er sich selbst nicht als solcher sieht</sup>

Comment: Das zweite Beispiel beschreibt vielleicht einen _Amerikaner mit asiatischer Vergangenheit_, aber wer in diesem Zusammenhang _Herkunft_ auf Geographie beschränkt, will missverstanden werden (was in diesem Themenkomplex nicht ungewöhnlich wäre, weil es die Absurdität aufzeigt). _*Asioamerikaner_ ist ungebräuchlich und morphologisch zweifelhaft. Man kann prinzipiell auch Bezeichnungen mit _asiatisiert_ bzw. _amerikanisiert_ konstruieren, die wiederum andere Facetten aufweisen.

Comment: @Crissov: *Das zweite Beispiel beschreibt vielleicht einen* Amerikaner mit asiatischer Vergangenheit, *aber wer in diesem Zusammenhang* Herkunft *auf Geographie beschränkt, will missverstanden werden* – Um des prohpezeiten Aufzeigens von Absurditäten willen: Wenn wir mal die Kontinente im zweiten Beispiel austauschen, würde [dieser Mensch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marron_Curtis_Fort) (welcher zumindest teilweise afrikanischer Herkunft ist) wohl allgemein als Deutscher amerikanischer Herkunft bezeichnet werden, oder?

Answer (score 0):

Ein *asiatischer Amerikaner* ist schriftlich das gleiche wie ein *Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft*, und zwar ein Bürger einer der 35  amerikanischen Länder, dessen Vorfahren (teilweise) asiatisch sind. Dafür ist *asiatischer Amerikaner* mündlich nicht ganz deutlich.

Die kontextunabhängige Verwendung *Amerikaner* als *US-Amerikaner* und  außerhalb der Umgangsprache ist, trotz deren Häufigkeit, schlicht falsch. In Amerika wohnen ca. 953,7 Millionen Menschen, von denen nur ca. ein Drittel, 319 Millionen, US-Bürger sind. Es sind mehr als 600 Millionen Menschen, die Recht haben, als Amerikaner annerkant zu werden, ohne US-Amerikaner zu sein. Genauso wie mehr als 80 Millionen deutscher Bürger das Recht haben, nicht *Franzosen* oder nicht *Finnen* gennant zu werden; genauso wie rund 8,5 Millionen Österreicher das Recht haben, nicht *Deutsche* bennant zu werden. *Asiatischer Amerikaner* und  *Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft* sind jeweils falsche Freunde von *Asian American*.

Was Häufigkeit angeht, ergibt sich den Vergliech für

> 1) [der] {asiatische + asiatischem +asiatischen} Amerikaner *und* 2) Amerikaner asiatischer Herkunft

wie folgt. Die Graphik ist aber mit Vorsicht zu genießen und muss nur als eine viel zu grobe Einschätzung empfunden werden:

[image]

Comment: Ob der Graph so viel aussagt? Es fehlen (unterschiedlich viele) deklinierte Formen. Außerdem wäre _Amerikaner asiatischer Abstammung_ zum Vergleich noch interessant.

Comment: @c.p. _Stammung_? Du meinst _Abstammung_. Man könnte natürlich [versuchen](http://goo.gl/7aQqdP), die Suche um _Typ_, _Aussehen_, _Phänotyp_, _Physiognomie_ oder sogar _Rasse_ zu erweitern, sinnvoller wird die Bezeichnung dadurch aber auch nicht.

Comment: Es wirkt ein wenig seltsam, wenn du von einem **Recht**, *Amerikaner* genannt zu werden, schreibst. Für die einzelnen Kontinente Nord- bzw. Südamerika funktioniert die Kontinentalzuordnung, aber bei *Amerikanern* denke ich immer an die Bürger der USA. Das ist auch in der Alten Welt zu beobachten - *Afrikaner* ruft keine Assoziationen mit den Mittelmeeranrainern hervor (Marokko bis Ägypten), bei *Asiaten* denkt man auch nicht an den Nahen Osten, Iran oder Sibirien. Diese Begriffe beziehen sich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch nicht wirklich auf die Kontinente.

Comment: @Chieron Seltsam ist hier rein statistisch. Dazu ist gar nicht klar, was Nordamerika ist (in Deutschland denkt man Nordamerika als ein aus zwei Ländern bestehender Kontinent, was nicht stimmt). Vielleicht würdest du das mit Recht verstehen, gäbe es eine Sprache, in dem man unter *Europäer* ausschließlich (sagen wir mal) *Franzose* verstehen würde.

Comment: @c.p. Dass Mexiko (usw.) nicht in Südamerika liegt, ist denke ich schon bekannt. Falls ich *Nordamerikaner* höre, denke ich nicht notwendigerweise nur an die USA und Kanada (der Ausdruck ist aber selten). Die Konstruktion US-Amerikaner ist hingegen nur bei uns verbreitet. So weit ich weiß, verstehen sich die Einwohner Lateinamerikas auch nicht als *Amerikaner*, machen also von diesem "Recht" auch nicht Gebrauch. Eine Sprache, in der das Wort für *Europäer* und *Franzose* zusammenfallen, wäre etwas seltsam. Andererseits sind ja gerade wir Deutschen oft durch Teilstämme identifiziert..